# Filtering elements of an array

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, filtering

I have an array as

[image]

That is, each item has its category in the following index.
I need all the items whose category are TotalNumbers and CurrentNumbers.

I tried

```
 int i = 1;
            foreach (string item in statsname)
            {
                 //only number type stats are added to the comboboxes.
                if ((statsname[i].ToUpperInvariant()==("TOTALNUMBER")) || ((statsname[i].ToUpperInvariant()==("CURRENTNUMBER"))))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(statsname[i-1]);
                    i++;
                    i++;
                }
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
```

Apparently this does not checks for what I need correctly.

How do I need to modify my codes to get what i need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's better to use a for loop instead of foreach:

```
for (int i = 1; i < statsname.Length; i += 2)
{
    //only number type stats are added to the comboboxes.
    if ((statsname[i].ToUpperInvariant()==("TOTALNUMBER")) || ((statsname[i].ToUpperInvariant()==("CURRENTNUMBER"))))
        comboBox1.Items.Add(statsname[i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq comes to rescue!

```
var listItems = from s in statsname where s.Equals("TOTALNUMBER", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || s.Equals("CURRENTNUMBER", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) select new ListItem(s);

comboBox1.AddRange(listItems);
```

Code not tested or compiled, but you can have an idea of what i said.

Comment: I DO NOT NEED to add the ones which are TotalNumber and CurrentNumber.I need to add the ONE ABOVE IT in the array.

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn You should have said so in the post then. Your post suggests otherwise: "I need all the items whose category are TotalNumbers and CurrentNumbers."

Comment: @dcastro , the post also mentioned "each item has its category in the following index". Which means the check condition is the TotalNumber and CurrentNumber but the display need to be the items of the index above these.

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn I get it now. Don't you think a `Dictionary<string, string>` would be a MUCH better fit for this?

Comment: Having an array where items with an odd index have a different meaning than items with an even index is a recipe for mayhem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredValues = Array.FindAll(source, s => s.ToUpperInvariant() == "TOTALNUMBER" ||
                                                            s.ToUpperInvariant() == "CURRENTNUMBER").ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using index in an foreach loop. The below code should work for you

```
foreach (string item in statsname)
        {

            if ( item.ToUpper() == "TOTALNUMBER" || item.ToUpper() == "CURRENTNUMBER")
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

            }

        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```